# Using a .cer instead of a .p12 to authenticate to a server on android

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, keystore, pkcs#12

for my current project we use a certificate authentification on our server. Till now we used PKCS12 to realise that and it was working fine. Because we integrated a PKCS11 security card now i can only get the certificate as a standard .cer. So far so good i can create a keystore and SSLcontext fine but for some reason the server doesn't recognize that im trying to use a certificate if i do it with a .cer. Maybe you guys can find a reason.

Working code:

```
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keystore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("/data/local/tmp/admin.p12")), certpw.toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, certpw.toCharArray());
ctx.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),
                    new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new X509Certificate[] {};
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(
                                final X509Certificate[] arg0,
                                final String arg1)
                                throws CertificateException {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(
                                final X509Certificate[] arg0,
                                final String arg1)
                                throws CertificateException {

                        }
                    } }, new SecureRandom());
```

And here the not working code with a .cer:

```
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/data/local/tmp/admin.cer");
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate caCert = (Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(is);

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(null, certpw.toCharArray());
ks.setCertificateEntry("caCert", caCert);

KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(ks, certpw.toCharArray());

ctx.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),
                    new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {

                        @Override
                        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new X509Certificate[] {};
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(
                                final X509Certificate[] arg0,
                                final String arg1)
                                throws CertificateException {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(
                                final X509Certificate[] arg0,
                                final String arg1)
                                throws CertificateException {

                        }
                    } }, new SecureRandom());
```

Basicly the only thing, that changed is that i create an empty keystore now and add the certificate manually.

EDIT: 
I get the .cer via JNI using a .so lib provided by the card manufactor. It contains an implementation of the PKCS#11 API. I could get the private and public key from the card together with the certificate but don't know how i would use those to make a KeysStore.

Answer (score 3):

You need the private key. With .p12 file you had it and it was used to establish SSL connection to the server.

When you moved from .p12 to smartcard you made a big change. I don't know if it will be possible to make KeyStore work with smartcard through a PKCS#11 interface or if a PKCS#11 interface is even available on android (I am not an android developer).

Try to do some research if it could be done. 
The questions you should be asking yourself (or google):

- Is PKCS#11 interface available on android?
- Does your vendor supply the card with a PKCS#11 library for android?
- Can KeyStore use a PKCS#11 library?

Comment: KeyStore can use a PKCS#11 libary but sadly not on android because its only available for "normal" java.
Yes i have a library from my vendor, a .so that i use to get the information via JNI, so using native C code and thats the only way im able to get the information from the card.
I can get the private key from the card, but what would i do with it?

Comment: If it can not be integrated with keystore then you will have to somehow implement SSLContext yourself or make your own implementation of KeyStore that can use PKCS#11 library on android.

Comment: So there is no easy way to just at the privat key to the keystore in aboves Code example?

Comment: Well, implement KeyStore yourself and you could use almost all from that code snippet. I would try to derive a class from KeyStore, implement/override the parts that need to communicate with smartcard through PKCS#11 interface and leave the rest to do by the base KeyStore class (if that's possible). Then instead of using KeyStore, use your own implementation in that code you pasted. But as I said, I am no android or java developer. I use c# but the principles should be the same.

Comment: @pepo is correct but this is not trivial on Android. Depending on how you access the smart card, it might require a custom build. Your best bet is to use the PKCS#12 file and import it into Android's native keystore. Otherwise look up the keymaster HAL interface in Android source code, there is one implementation that uses PKCS#11. You need to build something similar to integrate with Android's native keystore.